# What does ちょうどいっか mean here?

Tags: reading-comprehension, questions

[image]

[image]

In the first bubble, the character comments that "We did a bunch (of the stuff we needed to do)".

Then in the second line as I understand he adds
冬までにほとんど 終わりそうだけど
Looks like we'll be done by winter.

受験もあるし ちょうどいっか

What I'm not sure is the nuance in the second sentence.

"We also got exams." and... ちょうどいっか "Will it be alright?"

Is he wondering that despite the fact they should be done by winter completing their tasks, because of exams they may not make it?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ちょうどいい is used when something happens to be just right, when something happens to come in handy, when something turns out to be a lucky event, when someone appears at the perfect time, etc.

- 「おはよう」「ちょうどよかった！ 君の話をしてたんだ」
  "Good morning." "Perfect timing! We've been talking about you."
- この辺の写真を撮りたかったので、電車が止まってちょうどよかった。
  I wanted to take pictures around this area, so it was actually good that the train stopped.

In your context, they are a bit worried about having worked too hard on some task; they may have no work left to do after winter. However, they reconsidered it, saying "There will be entrance exams, so it's probably just right (we didn't overdo this)".